# Resolving left-recursion in my grammar

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, grammar, left-recursion

My grammar has a case of left-recursion in the sixth production rule.

[image: Left recursion]

I resolved this by replacing Rule 6 and 7 like this:

[image: Resolved left recursion]

I couldn't find any indirect left recursions in this grammar.

The only thing that bothers me is the final production rule, which has a terminal surrounded by two non-terminals.

My two questions are:

- Is my resolved left recursion correct?
- Is the final production rule a left recursion?  I am not sure how to
  treat this special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your resolution is correct.  You may want to remove the epsilon rule for ease of use, but the accepted strings are correct.

```
X -> -
X -> -Z
Z -> +
Z -> +Z
Z -> X + Y
... and Y is of the form 0* 1 (no syntax collisions)
```

As a check, note that you *could* now replace this final rule with two new rules, one for each expansion of X:

```
Z -> -  + Y
Z -> -Z + Y
```

This removes X entirely from the Z rules, and each Z rule would then begin with a terminal.

No, your final production rule is no longer left-recursive.  X now must resolve to a string beginning with a non-terminal.

I have to admit, though, I'm curious about what use the language has.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful clarification.


This grammar has just been used for learning purposes in order to understand the concept of resolving left recursions, thus it has no real application!